# How do I protect a shell script from being downloaded?

Tags: security, shell

I have a shell script which is called by a cron job. I don't want it to be downloaded via a browser. I have tried the filesmatch htaccess directive but that doesn't seem to stop me calling the url of the file and downloading it.

How can I protect it?

Comment: Does it have to be under a folder published by your web server?

Comment: which web server are you using?
Why are you exposing it in a browseable directory first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't put it under your webroot.

Answer (score 3):

move it outside of a web accessible dir

Answer (score 0):

Move it out of the directory tree the webserver is serving from. If it's not being invoked by the webserver, it doesn't need to be there.